# Major issue: Dropdown switcher in Mezzanine uses default settings of main site when logged in

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mezzanine

In Mezzanine there's a dropdown list of available sites on the multi tenancy project that I created.

The problem is when a user is logging in to their blog e.g. blog.domain.com the user gets the default choice of domain.com and so their posts etc won't show up for some reason. It's not even public when I am logged out also...

**The source of this switcher:**

```
{% if dropdown_menu_sites and dropdown_menu_sites|length > 1 %}
<form action="{% url "set_site" %}">
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">
<select name="site_id" onchange="this.form.submit();">
{% for site in dropdown_menu_sites %}
<option value="{{ site.id }}"
    {% if site.id == dropdown_menu_selected_site_id %} selected{% endif %}
    >{{ site }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

I can't really figure out what's causing this and how to modify it so that the blogger can login and expect to have control over their settings for the blog.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works. According to Stephen McDonald (the creator) he says (quote):

**Some things to note:**

- Site selector in admin won't change the URL being used to access the
  admin over, it sets a session variable controlling which site data is
  being used - this is so that the admin can always be access over a
  single domain which may be the only one containing an SSL
  certificate.
- If you view the front-end site as a logged-in administrator with the
  session variable set, that site's data will be used regardless of the
  host being accessed - this is so that the content administrator can
  preview their changes, regardless of which host their authenticated
  session is tied to.

**Link:** https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/1467#issuecomment-165626948